# Options in second select depending on selected option in first select

Tags: node.js, slack

Is it possible to create a node.js slack app where users can choose car make in one select menu and then car model in another select menu where the options in the second select menu depends on what car make was choosen in the first menu?

The solution I am looking for could either be in a slack message, in a dialog or chained (if that is a thing).

I have found great examples with only one select menu but I really need to be able to create a pattern where C depends on choices in B and B depends on choices in A etc.

Hopefully someone understands what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to implement a select menu depending on the input of a prior select menu is to post one after the other.

Here is a basic outline:

1. App post message with select menu A
2. User makes choice and app receives request from Slack with choice for A
3. App overwrite prior message with select menu B based on choice from A

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar goal - 2 static select boxes in a Slack modal *(using Blocks UI)*. The reason for the change was that the number of options started to exceed 100  and this breaks the app *(limit by Slack)*. So we needed the first Select to essentially filter/determine the available options for the second Select.

As I was surprised to find that there are no easy/straightforward answers to this, then here goes my solution:

1. Make the "first" Select to trigger an action by setting `dispatch_action` to `true` in your Blocks UI definition.

```
{
  "type": "input",
  "dispatch_action": true,
  "element": {
    "type": "static_select",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

This will now trigger a HTTP POST to your [Interactivity URL](https://api.slack.com/interactivity) with `type:block_actions`. You can configure it on your app's config page. Something like `https://api.slack.com/apps/YourAppIdHere/interactive-messages`

2. You can now take that same **view** via `req.body.payload.view` and the **action** that just took place via `req.body.payload.actions` and do your modifications to the view. E.g. you can take the old view and overwrite the second Select component based on the value in your `actions`
3. Now use the Slack [views.update](https://api.slack.com/methods/views.update) request to update your view. You have to pass the new/changed `view` object and the `view_id` with it.

```
await web.views.update({
    token: WEBCLIENT_TOKEN,
    view: yourEditedView,
    view_id: req.body.payload.view.id
})
```

4. You'll probably have to follow and clean up the Slack errors to get everything aligned *(E.g. can't just pass on a full `view` object that comes from Slack POST, but have to remove some properties first)*, but that's the gist of it. You should have a conditionally rendered options in the second Select component.